# Windows cluster anti-affinity - what am I missing?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-cluster

I'm attempting to set up anti-affinity rules in a two-node Windows 2012 cluster. I'm doing something like:

```
$value = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection;
$value.Add('ArbitraryString');
(get-clustergroup group1).AntiAffinityClassNames = $value;
(get-clustergroup group2).AntiAffinityClassNames = $value;
```

Before I initiate a failover, group1 and group2 are on different nodes. However, after I initiate a failover of group1, group2 doesn't move away from group1. What am I missing?

It should be noted that one of these groups is a SQL Availability Group (the other is not; I just don't want it to be hosted on the same node as the primary for the AG). So, failover of that group isn't initiated through cluster administrator, but rather through SQL Server. I don't think it's relevant, but just in case it is…

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. If you only have two cluster nodes and one cluster node fails then what choice is there but to put both groups on the same cluster node?

Comment: With a SQL AG, the secondary node is available for read-only traffic. We're attempting to create an IP address that follows the secondary node so our applications can hit it.

Comment: @BenThul - did you find an answer for this? I'm having the same behaviour and I think I'm missing something simple.

Comment: No. From what I recall, the anti-affinity stuff was marked as being only for Hyper-V or something. Which is unfortunate.